# How to list files by when it was first added to a Git repo?

Tags: git

How do you find the most recently added files in git, on a Linux OS?

Using `git log` on every file is not feasible.

And `git ls-files` shows the full list of files, but I don't see any dates associated with them.

Comment: By "creation date" do you mean when it was first committed to the repo?

Comment: Yes, creation date would be when it's first added to the repo.  Thanks, I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to run `git log` on "every file". You only need to run it once. Use something like `git log --name-status --format=%H` which produces output like this:

```
aa56a2ff6a56697342908cc0cc85a537ecea4325

A   changelogs/fragments/70887_galaxy_token.yml
M   lib/ansible/galaxy/token.py
932ba3616067007fd5e449611a34e7e3837fc8ae

M   lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py
M   lib/ansible/modules/get_url.py
A   test/integration/targets/unsafe_writes/aliases
A   test/integration/targets/unsafe_writes/basic.yml
[...]
```

For each commit, this lists the files involved and their status, where `M` is "modified", `A` is added, etc.

Now just look for lines that start with `A<tab>`:

```
$ git log --name-status --format=%H | awk -F'\t' '$1 == "A" {print}'
A       changelogs/fragments/70887_galaxy_token.yml
A       test/integration/targets/unsafe_writes/aliases
A       test/integration/targets/unsafe_writes/basic.yml
[...]
```

The most recently added files are the ones at the top of the list.

Comment: Nice.  But the awk 'A' seemed to give problems.  I replaced single with double quotes and it worked:  git log --name-status --format=%H | awk -F'\t' '$1 == "A" {print}'

Comment: Yeah, sorry, typo on my part. Fixing that.

Answer (score 2):

```
git log --name-status --diff-filter=A
```

See [the docs about `--diff-filter`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-filterACDMRTUXB82308203).

Comment: `git log ---pretty= --name-only --diff-filter=A`

Answer (score 0):

Creation dates, but it still takes a long time:

```
for file in $(git ls-files); do echo -n "$file "; git log --format=%ai $file | tail -1; done
```

Last modified dates is the same but use head instead of tail:

```
for file in $(git ls-files); do echo -n "$file "; git log --format=%ai $file | tail -1; done
```